# Code First —Why can't I see the database which was created

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-first

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AnalysedCompanies" 
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|AnalysedCompanies.sdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>

public class AnalysedCompanies:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.MinisterulFinantelorData> DateMinisterulFinantelor { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.ONRCData> DateONRC { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.InsolventaData> DateInsolventa { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.Bilant> Bilant { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.ContProfitSiPierdere> ContProfitSiPierdere { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.DateInformativeBilant> DateInformativeBilant { get; set; }  
}
```

Why can't I see the sdf file created in the solution explorer? Show all files is active.

The data is saved, because I can retrieve it the next time I run, but I can't see my database that Code First should create.

Answer (score 1):

The .sdf file will be located in the App_Data or Debug/Release/executing directory depending on the type of application.

You must 'Refresh' those directories before you'll see new files.

Answer (score 1):

Code First uses many conventions, for connection strings, it uses a connection string based on the fully qualified type of the data context, which includes the namespace.  So you need to name your connectionstring `yournamespace.AnalysedCompanies` rather than just `AnalysedCompanies`.  Otherwise, EF uses a connection string based on defaults, which is to create a new database in the local SQLExpress or LocalDB with that name.

Alternatively, you can pass the connection string you want to use to the DbContext using the constructor that takes a connection string or name:

```
 public AnalysedCompanies() : base ("name=AnalysedCompanies") {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ( especially if there is another connection string to a SQL server Express instance running on the machine ) the DbContext will ignore the named connection string, and will create your tables on the Express database, rather than a CE sdf.

One way to ensure that your context uses your named context is to force it in the constructor method of your datacontext.

```
 public class AnalysedCompanies:DbContext
    {
        public AnalysedCompanies() : base ("AnalysedCompanies") {}

        public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.MinisterulFinantelorData> DateMinisterulFinantelor { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.ONRCData> DateONRC { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.InsolventaData> DateInsolventa { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.Bilant> Bilant { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.ContProfitSiPierdere> ContProfitSiPierdere { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CompanyAnalyse.WebServiceLibrary.DateInformativeBilant> DateInformativeBilant { get; set; }


    }
```

At this point, your DbContext should exploit the named connection, and create the file in the expected location.

Comment: I believe that should be "name=AnalysedCompanies", if you don't include name= then it assumes that it is a literal connection string